# ng-bind is not working with function call

Tags: angularjs

I would like to bind current date and time with a span,

```
<span id="lastUpdated" ng-bind="'loadMessage'"></span>
```

I returning the value of "loadMessage" from a function, but it's not working,

```
$scope.loadMessage = updateInfo();

function updateInfo() {
var today = new Date();
return "Last updated " + today.toLocaleString() + ".";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you wanted to get date value at initial load only. You don't need to have `'`(single qoute) around your `ng-bind` expression so that it will take from `$scope`

```
<span id="lastUpdated" ng-bind="loadMessage"></span>
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dXPRTqBdUuwbB3PmvDpJ?p=preview)

Comment: this doesn't load the content

Comment: @user584018 what do you mean by it doesn't load the content?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this,

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="namectrl">
    <span id="lastUpdated" ng-bind="loadMessage()"></span>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.loadMessage = function() {
     var today = new Date();
     return "Last updated " + today.toLocaleString() + ".";
   }
```

[**Demo App**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vMsbQxkFGlqxtrkFpszt?p=preview)

Comment: `$scope.loadMessage = updateInfo() assigns the result of updateInfo() to the $scope. loadMessage is not a function.

Comment: @water42 just go through my answer, its a function according to my answer

Comment: Sorry my comment was somewhat unclear. In the original post the OP assigns the value of `updateInfo()` to `$scope.loadMessage`. He does NOT assign `updateInfo`, the function, to `$scope.loadMessage`. I downvoted since this answer arbitrarily changes the original functionality, and doesn't address why the original code wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes in the ng-bind statement and it will work:

`Hello <span ng-bind="loadMessage"></span>!`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes as @Pankaj Parkar suggested and do $scope.$apply(); after calling updateInfo function. It should be going out of digest cycle.

Comment: no need to run `$scope.$apply` will make fall into error

Comment: It will depend on where he have written $scope.loadMessage = updateInfo();  to call it. He could have written it outside controller init and may be getting called after the dom loading/digest cycle is completed.

Comment: What do mean by that?

Comment: The script which he have posted could be written inside some other function which may be getting called on some other event. This could happen when you are following some angular style guide to make the code more modular as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to bind value using a function, then

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   {{getFee(app.subject)}}
</div>
```

You can call the function like this,

```
$scope.getFee = function (id) {
    var fees = '';
    $scope.subjects.forEach(element => {
       if (element.subject == id) {
          fees = element.subjectDetails.examFee;
          return false;
       }
    });
    return fees;
}
```